# Spark rdd handle java date bug

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, rdd, simpledateformat

I've been confused by this bug for a couple of days. I felt it might be some Java date problems.

Here is the code:

```scala
val rdd1 = some_rdd1.map { x =>
  (x._1, x._2)
}

val rdd2 = some_rdd2.map { x =>
  (x._1, x._2)
}

val formatter2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddmmss")

val res_rdd = rdd1.join(rdd2).map { case(id, (tm, value)) =>
  val format_time = {
    //tm is a unix timestamp, long type
    val cur_time = new Date(tm*1000L)
    val time_format = formatter2.format(cur_time)
      time_format
  }
  val format_time2 = {
    //tm is a unix timestamp, long type
    val cur_time = new Date(tm*1000L)
    val time_format = formatter2.format(cur_time)
      time_format
  }

  if (format_time!= format_time2) {
        println(s"""format_time: ${format_time}, format_time2: ${format_time2}, click_time: ${tm}""")
      }

  (tm, format_time, format_time2, value)
}
//...
//some actions
```

I thought `format_time` and `format_time2` should be the same, so the print things should not appear. However, I got following stdout from executors:

```
format_time: 201810251433, format_time2: 201810251241, click_time: 1540442502
format_time: 201810250757, format_time2: 201810250924, click_time: 1540430650
format_time: 201810250738, format_time2: 201810250701, click_time: 1540422067
format_time: 201810251415, format_time2: 201810250738, click_time: 1540448140
format_time: 201810250503, format_time2: 201810251400, click_time: 1540447255
format_time: 201810250831, format_time2: 201810250836, click_time: 1540427797
format_time: 201810251203, format_time2: 201810250901, click_time: 1540429284
format_time: 201810250729, format_time2: 201810250910, click_time: 1540429821
```

I have around 14 million data, and about 60k `format_time` and `format_time2` are not the same. I have no idea why does this happen?

Comment: In short `SimpleDateFormat` is not thread safe - it cannot be used like this. You should create thread local instance each time or use `mapPartitions`.

Comment: oh, thanks. Why `mapPartitions` can solve such problem?